# Output array from selected data

Tags: php, html

I have an array which contains data from different forms. I need a way to grab the arrays  where form_name = demographics and output them.

I have tried a while loop to find the arrays that include the form_name 'demographics' but I get a result of nothing

This array is being generated by:

```
$question_set_p1 = [];
$num_questions_set_p1 = count($choice_set_p1);

//get the keys from the choice_set array
$question_num_p1 = array_keys($choice_set_p1);

for($i = 0; $i < $num_questions_set_p1; $i++){
    $question_set_p1[] = $tyler->prepQuestion($data_dictionary_p1, $choice_set_p1, $question_num_p1, $i);
}
```

The array in contender:

```
[1]=>
  array(11) {
    ["field_label"]=>
    string(24) "What is your first name?"
    ["field_name"]=>
    string(6) "f_name"
    ["identifier"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["options"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["form_name"]=>
    string(12) "demographics"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(11) {
    ["field_label"]=>
    string(23) "What is your last name?"
    ["field_name"]=>
    string(6) "l_name"
    ["identifier"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["options"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["form_name"]=>
    string(12) "demographics"
  }
[3]=>
  array(11) {
    ["field_label"]=>
    string(32) "Researcher who took measurements"
    ["field_name"]=>
    string(17) "weight_researcher"
    ["identifier"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["options"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["form_name"]=>
    string(6) "weight"
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To grab the data, you can use [`array_filter()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

```
$data = array_filter($data, function($arr){ return $arr['form_name'] === 'demographics'; });
```

As for outputting it, that depends entirely on what format you want it outputting in, what data needs showing, etc. and I can't really give you a worthwhile demo of that. It's pretty straightforward to do, anyhow.

Comment: Now if I want to use the same script to find where the form_name == weight I am not able to grab that data and display it. Its because weight is #3 in the array not #1 in the array. How can I get that?

Comment: No, it's because we're overwriting the `$data` array with the demographics-only version. Just change the `$data = ` part to `$demographicsData = ` then you can copy/paste the line and make it `$weightData = ` and it should work :-)

Comment: Is there a way to change the array number so when it filters, it assigns it a new array number? (Just a thought)

Comment: Yes, you call the variable you're assigning it into something different :-P

Comment: I'm sorry that I am new to this but  its not this is it? $data =  array_filter($question_set_p1, function($arr){ return $arr['form_name'] === 'weight; });

$new_array = array();
foreach ($data as $datanew){
    $datanew = $data;
}

Comment: Just `$demographicsData = array_filter($question_set_p1...` then `$weightData = array_filter($question_set_p1...` should do it